# Filling missing values based on a relationship with another table

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data tables, `city_pop`, and `city_sub`. `city_pop` is a list of cities with average population with some values missing. The `city_sub` table gives two possible `city_id` (`sub_1` and `sub_2`) whose `avg_pop` can be used to fill `NA` in `city_pop`. `sub_1` and `sub_2` are to be used in that order of preference. Only the `NA` values in `avg_pop` need to be replaced.

How can I do this without using for loops?

```
city_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
avg_pop = c(100, NA, NA, 300, 400, NA)

city_pop = data.table(city_id, avg_pop)

   city_id avg_pop
1:       1     100
2:       2      NA
3:       3      NA
4:       4     300
5:       5     400
6:       6      NA

sub_1=c(2,1,4,3,1,3)
sub_2=c(5,5,6,6,2,4)

city_sub =data.table(city_id,sub_1,sub_2)

   city_id sub_1 sub_2
1:       1     2     5
2:       2     1     5
3:       3     4     6
4:       4     3     6
5:       5     1     2
6:       6     3     4
```

Expected Output -

```
  city_id avg_pop
1       1     100
2       2     100
3       3     300
4       4     300
5       5     400
6       6     300
```

Comment: Hi, why is city 6  value 300?

Comment: for city 6, closest one are 3 and 4, and 3 has a missing value in city_pop. so the next one is 4, which has 300.

Comment: And how do we know 3 and 4 are the closest?

Comment: @M--, city_sub is created from a different relationship. don't care if the values doesn't make sense. Assuming that it is correct, can you help me?

Comment: @Bhagya I can read the frustration between the lines and I understand trying to figure out a problem can be a frustrating matter. If you search along SO you'll see that people are getting help almost every second. The reason we are asking these questions is to understand your problem and your logic that you want to take towards solving it. If we get that, this looks like a simple problem which I believe we can help you to solve. If we don't get the reasoning, then how we are supposed to solve a problem we failed to comprehend.

Comment: Saying that, when you say "*Here sub_1 is the first candidate, and sub_2 is the second candidate if sub_1 avg_pop is not available for imputing data.*"confuses me. At first, I thought `sub_1` and `sub_2` are coupled, meaning if `2` is missing `5` will be the candidate to replace. Now, I quite don't know how you decide which city will be replacement for a missing one. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @M-- @eyllanesc @JimGarrison I have edited the question to improve clarity. The question is not about finding the closest city but simply about using the given substitutes to replace `NA` values. Consider reopening. @Bhagya Hope my changes make sense. If not, consider adding more clarification.

Comment: @Shree You only can mention one handle in a comment. I am the only one seeing this. Honestly, it is still unclear to me.

Comment: @M-- Thanks for the handle info; didn't know. I edited based on how I understood the question but I'll let OP add more clarity if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way with `dplyr` using `coalesce` which uses the first non-`NA` value. I created a separate column `avg_pop2` as it seems safer in this case and also makes it easy to validate the result.

```
city_pop %>% 
  left_join(city_sub, by = "city_id") %>% 
  mutate(
    avg_pop2 = coalesce(
      avg_pop, avg_pop[match(sub_1, city_id)], avg_pop[match(sub_2, city_id)]
    )
  )

  city_id avg_pop sub_1 sub_2 avg_pop2
1       1     100     2     5      100
2       2      NA     1     5      100
3       3      NA     4     6      300
4       4     300     3     6      300
5       5     400     1     2      400
6       6      NA     3     4      300
```

Comment: This is clever but would cause issues if the ```city_id``` had missing numbers or started at a number other than one. ```c(2, 3, 5``` is an example. Still, I like it

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to look up sub_1, then look up its avg_pop; then do the same for sub_2:

```
city_pop[is.na(avg_pop), avg_pop :=  
  city_pop[.(city_sub[.SD, on=.(city_id), x.sub_1]), on=.(city_id), x.avg_pop]
]
city_pop[is.na(avg_pop), avg_pop := 
  city_pop[.(city_sub[.SD, on=.(city_id), x.sub_2]), on=.(city_id), x.avg_pop]
]
```

This approach is kind of convoluted and would not work for more general examples. A graph theory approach might make more sense, eg, if city_sub looks like this:

```
   city_id sub_1 
1:       1     5 
5:       5     3
```

Suppose 1 & 5 both have missing data. We would expect to see 5 filled with 3, then 1 filled with 5, but this requires knowing in which order to fill. With a directed graph, you could figure out the right order of traversal, I guess, though I haven't thought through the details.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach is to convert `city_sub` into a long format and tweak the `city_id` in the decimal place before using a rolling join:

```
          #convert into long format
newpop <- melt(city_sub, measure.vars=patterns("^sub_"), variable.factor=FALSE)[,
    #tweak the city_id slightly to show order of preference
    city_id := as.numeric(paste0(city_id, ".", substring(variable, nchar(variable))))][
        #look up average population
        city_pop, on=.(value=city_id), new_pop := i.avg_pop][
            #remove cities without population
            !is.na(new_pop)]
newpop
#   city_id variable value new_pop
#1:     2.1    sub_1     1     100
#2:     3.1    sub_1     4     300
#3:     5.1    sub_1     1     100
#4:     1.2    sub_2     5     400
#5:     2.2    sub_2     5     400
#6:     6.2    sub_2     4     300

#rolling join
city_pop[is.na(avg_pop), avg_pop :=
        newpop[copy(.SD), on=.(city_id), roll=-Inf, x.new_pop]]
```

output:

```
   city_id avg_pop
1:       1     100
2:       2     100
3:       3     300
4:       4     300
5:       5     400
6:       6     300
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
city_pop = data.table(city_id=1:6, avg_pop=c(100, NA, NA, 300, 400, NA))
city_sub = data.table(city_id=1:6, sub_1=c(2,1,4,3,1,3), sub_2=c(5,5,6,6,2,4))
```